# Using a cell array within datenum, convert to string with format before necessary?

Tags: matlab

> Closed. This question needs debugging details. It is not currently accepting answers.
> Edit the question to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. This will help others answer the question.
> Closed 11 hours ago.

(Private feedback for you)

From reading in this Excel file into MATLAB:

`[frates, fdlable] = xlsread('C:\Users\Nancy\Documents\Research\Data\USTreasury\USTreasuryDataset\FredTreasuryRatesMon','A8:X818')`

I get a cell array rates `fdlable1` `811 by 12` of Excel dates, format `m/d/yyyy` that I want convert to serial date numbers through `datenum`.

Must I convert `fdlable1` `'m/d/yyyy'` to a string variable first before using `datenum`?

Here the assignment fails because there are empty cells in `fdlable1`:

`date_num = cellfun(@datenum, fdlable1, 'UniformOutput', false);`

> Warning: Usage of DATENUM with empty date character vectors or empty strings is not supported. Results may change in future versions.

`fdlable1 =fdlable(:,1:2:23);`

```
811 x 12 from 811 x 23
fdlable: '7/1/1954' '' '7/1/2001' '' '1/1/1934' '' '12/1/1958' '8/1/1954' '' '8/1/2001' '' '2/1/1934' '' '1/1/1959' '9/1/1954' '' '9/1/2001' '' '3/1/1934' '' '2/1/1959' '10/1/1954' '' '10/1/2001' '' '4/1/1934' '' '3/1/1959' '11/1/1954' '' '11/1/2001' '' '5/1/1934' '' '4/1/1959' '12/1/1954' '' '12/1/2001' '' '6/1/1934' '' '5/1/1959' '1/1/1955' '' '1/1/2002' '' '7/1/1934' '' '6/1/1959' '2/1/1955' '' '2/1/2002' '' '8/1/1934' '' '7/1/1959' '3/1/1955' '' '3/1/2002' '' '9/1/1934' '' '8/1/1959' '4/1/1955' '' '4/1/2002' '' '10/1/1934' '' '9/1/1959' '5/1/1955' '' '5/1/2002' '' '11/1/1934' '' '10/1/1959' '6/1/1955' '' '6/1/2002' '' '12/1/1934' '' '11/1/1959' '7/1/1955' '' '7/1/2002' '' '1/1/1935' '' '12/1/1959' '8/1/1955' '' '8/1/2002' '' '2/1/1935' '' '1/1/1960'

fdlable1: '7/1/1954' '7/1/2001' '1/1/1934' '12/1/1958' '7/1/1959' '4/1/1953' '8/1/1954' '8/1/2001' '2/1/1934' '1/1/1959' '8/1/1959' '5/1/1953' '9/1/1954' '9/1/2001' '3/1/1934' '2/1/1959' '9/1/1959' '6/1/1953' '10/1/1954' '10/1/2001' '4/1/1934' '3/1/1959' '10/1/1959' '7/1/1953' '11/1/1954' '11/1/2001' '5/1/1934' '4/1/1959' '11/1/1959' '8/1/1953' '12/1/1954' '12/1/2001' '6/1/1934' '5/1/1959' '12/1/1959' '9/1/1953' '1/1/1955' '1/1/2002' '7/1/1934' '6/1/1959' '1/1/1960' '10/1/1953' '2/1/1955' '2/1/2002' '8/1/1934' '7/1/1959' '2/1/1960' '11/1/1953' '3/1/1955' '3/1/2002' '9/1/1934' '8/1/1959' '3/1/1960' '12/1/1953' '4/1/1955' '4/1/2002' '10/1/1934' '9/1/1959' '4/1/1960' '1/1/1954'
```

How to get a matrix of serial date numbers?

The corresponding variable rates is:

`rates = frates(:,1:2:23); 811 x 12`

```
0.800000000000000   3.61000000000000    0.720000000000000   3.01000000000000
1.22000000000000    3.48000000000000    0.620000000000000   3.09000000000000
1.07000000000000    2.63000000000000    0.240000000000000   3.13000000000000
0.850000000000000   2.24000000000000    0.150000000000000   3.13000000000000
0.830000000000000   1.96000000000000    0.160000000000000   3.27000000000000
1.28000000000000    1.69000000000000    0.150000000000000   3.33000000000000
1.39000000000000    1.65000000000000    0.150000000000000   3.52000000000000
1.29000000000000    1.70000000000000    0.190000000000000   3.82000000000000
1.35000000000000    1.75000000000000    0.210000000000000   3.87000000000000
1.43000000000000    1.69000000000000    0.270000000000000   4.70000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

`datenum` can not process empty data cells.  On a smaller data set
this works:

```
date_num = cellfun(@datenum, fdlable1(1:231,:), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Comment: I don't understand how you get the answer. In the question you used `date_num = cellfun(@datenum, fdlable1, 'UniformOutput', false);` and in the answer you used `date_num = cellfun(@datenum, fdlable1(1:231,:), 'UniformOutput', false);`. How do we should answer when we have not seen a minimal, complete and verifiable example?